# one issue related to ArrayObject in php

Tags: php

```
 <?php
    class ExtendedArrayObject extends ArrayObject {
        private $_array;
        public function __construct()
        {
            if (is_array(func_get_arg(0)))
                $this->_array = func_get_arg(0);
            else
                $this->_array = func_get_args();
            parent::__construct($this->_array);
        }
    }
    $newArray = new ExtendedArrayObject(array(1,2,3,4,5,6));
   ...
    ?>
```

Above code is taken from a book.

Question:
what is the usage of this line: `else $this->_array = func_get_args();`? why we need to set up a `if...else...`here?

Comment: `func_get_arg(0)` get the first argument of the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`func_get_args` contains an array of the parameters that were passed to the function.

By checking it the first item in this is an array in itself, it's saying to use that array.

If it's not, then use the full list of parameters.

An example of when the `if` would be run:

```
$newArray = new ExtendedArrayObject(array(1,2,3,4,5,6));
```

An example of when the `else` would be run

```
$newArray = new ExtendedArrayObject(1,2,3,4,5,6);
```

Answer (score 0):

func_get_args — Returns an array comprising a function's argument list.

Here it is if else because,

because if argument is more than 1 in function it will be an array hence it will be executing if condition or else it check code inside else  statement.

Answer (score 0):

The conditional is there to make a distinction between different results of `func_get_arg()`. If this is an array, it gets the first result, and if it isn't (the else) it gets the complete result.

`func_get_args()` Gets the specified argument from a user-defined function's argument list.